# How does the RequestMappingHandlerMapping handler maps the url to controller classes?

Tags: java, spring

As per my knowledge, in spring MVC, mappings declared via the @RequestMapping annotation are mapped via RequestMappingHandlerMapping handler.

Can someone please explain how is the mapping between web request and controller done by RequestMappingHandlerMapping.

Since we don't explicitly declare this handler mapping bean in the configuration file, is this registered by default? Is this the only handler which can be used with @RequestMapping?

Comment: Why don't you search this keyword in google - `@RequestMapping docs`

Comment: The docs i have come across do not explain how the mapping takes place. They just mention RequestMappingHandlerMapping  is used along with @RequestMapping and other annotations.